# OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature Accuracy problem

Tags: openlayers-2, coordinate-system

When i draw a polygon using the [OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Control/DrawFeature-js.html) then i export that polygon to KML using [OpenLayers.Format.KML](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Format/KML-js.html). Though, when I open it in google earth there is a big difference between the areas the polygon crosses even though the vertices of that polygon are exactly the same.

**WHY?** How would i go about getting an accurate output to KML?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be just an issue with projection?  Are your line's 2 endpoints in the "right" place on both maps?  If so, maybe you should put more intermediary points along the way to "help" the line be in the right place in any projection.

Comment: Yes, the line endpoints are in the "right" place. I guess that's what i'm going to have to do.